# Looking for JSON schema inside JsonObject

Tags: android, gson, json

I am downloading JSON object from remote server and converting it to simple POJO (using gson lib).

 I know JSON's schema, let's say it looks like this:

```
{
    "a": "something",
    "c": "something",
    "e": "something"
  }
```

However, JSON response might be placed inside many different wrapper-fields, like:

```
{
    "some_name":
    {
     "a": "b",
     "c": "d",
     "e": "f"
    }
}

{
    "some_name":
    {
        "some_other_name":
        {
          "a": "b",
          "c": "d",
          "e": "f"
        }
    }
}
```

I can reach to actual content with couple of ifs, but I am wondering if there's a way to look for given schema inside all fields to get desired content. 
 
Should I look through `JsonObject`'s `entrySet` and check every value or is there any faster/better method for that?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "schema" in JSON; its a serialization. If your server is returning randomly structured objects then you either need to fix that, or manually inspect the objects it's returning as you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up with looping through `entrySet` and looking for a my pattern.

Answer (score 0):

check out the gson library, I think you'll like it

https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

also, even with gson, it will help you to know what the JSON is going to look like( it *is* an interface we're dealing with, yes? =] ) and prepare a set of classes that represent that. Remember that in android( and any well-written java for that matter ), we don't use getters and setters when assigning values to feilds in an object; we just make them public and address them directly. ( I see getters and setters used as if they were protecting the feilds they are directly accessing far, far too often for comfort )

so you get a set of classes like this

```
class OuterClassName{
    public List<Apple> apples;
    public String picker;
}

class Apple{
    public int worms;
    public String color;
}
```

that are basically structs, and are mapped to the JSON response. Once you have that, everything is much easier. ProTip: if you are also writing the server code, and it is in Java, these classes already exist; git submodule those ftw.

Comment: I'm sorry, but... what? This question is clearly marked as gson-related. I even mentioned class and methods used by this library. And yes, I do know how to parse JSONs to Java classes. Lastly, who told you that making instance variables public is a good practice?

Comment: maybe I'm missing your question: does the server have a defined interface, or are you trying to download a number of different sorts of data, and are looking for a good way to tell what you are downloading?

Comment: To expand, you should consider what you are trying to do with your getters and setters, if blindly writing getter/setters for your private feilds is doing *anything* to help that ( it's not ), then check out this: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html

Comment: I want to look for defined schema in JsonObject, to pull it out from a bunch of wrapper fields.

Comment: I don't think you understood it correctly. Doc is talking about _internal_ getters and setters (within a class, not outside of it!).

Comment: yes, but those wrapper fields are fairly constant, yeah? they likely come from an API call that is returning a well-defined schema that you should be able to model once, not have to adapt to

Comment: it really doesn't matter: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073723/core-java/why-getter-and-setter-methods-are-evil.html

Comment: Yes, they are constant. But it would be nice to have one universal parsing method which will handle all these wrapper-fields. I am just lazy ;)

Comment: I hear that... I wish the same thing every time I deal with a new API! Possibly you can do like you are saying, and reflect a structure based on an initial parsing, but I'd also think someone would have published that code ( and you'd want to serialize the result per API so the app isn't auto-parsing a JSON every time... or just make it a tool for developement! ). I guess the only thing I have left to contribute is: xkcd.com/1205 and an upvote =]

Comment: Actually, I lied and kept thinking about this: if you are going to go down this road, consider making a Builder.